# rounded corner issues with IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

I have a site [Mumbai Local Train Time Table](http://www.MumbaiLocalTrainTimeTable.Net).

I am using asp.net Ajax dll 3.5. in which I use Rounded Corner extension. I see IE is not showing Rounded corners. It works fine with Chrome and Firefox.

what am i missing?

Comment: what version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: are u sure you can view it in IE 8 ? i tried but i looks like something bad .sorry to say that but i just want to help

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified what version of IE you're testing with, which is an important detail, but I'll try to help anyway.

Firstly IE8 and earlier do not support the CSS `border-radius` style that does the rounded corners. So if you're testing with IE8 or earlier (or if you need to support users who are using them), it is no surprise that you're not setting the rounded corners.

There are two options for you:

- Ignore it, and let users of old IE versions live with square corners. (it's not the worst thing in the world... and it won't affect the site usability, so why not)
- Use a javascript tool like [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) which implements the `border-radius` feature into old versions of IE.

If you're using IE9 or IE10 and you're still not seeing the `border-radius`, then the problem is most likely to be that the browser is going into compatibility mode, or worse, Quirks mode.

Quirksmode can be resolved by having a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` at the top of the page. I note that you do have a doctype, but I also note that you have a blank line above it.
**Important**: The doctype *must* be the very first thing in the page. Even a bit of white space or a comment above it will cause IE to ignore it and fall back to quirks mode. You really don't want that.

Compatiblity mode: If this is the problem, you can usually resolve it by adding a meta tag to the document as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I hope that helps.